# New and FromArgb in 1 line

Tags: vb.net, colors

I have these 2 lines to create a color:

```
Dim nCol As New Color
nCol = Color.FromArgb(200, 200, 200)
```

I was hoping I could simplify it by something like

```
Dim nCol As New Color = Color.FromArgb(200, 200, 200)
```

or

```
Dim nCol As Color.FromArgb(200, 200, 200)
```

but none of my attempts would compile.

Can this be done in a single statement and if yes, how?

Comment: You shouldn't call _**both**_ `New` and `FromArgb`. Both options create a new instance, so only the `FromArgb` call is necessary: `Dim nCol As Color = Color.FromArgb(200, 200, 200)`.

Comment: `As New` is a shorthand for `Dim nColor As Color = New Color` which means you are setting the variable _**twice**_. Do not use `New` if you are going to set it to something else anyway (in this case `= Color.FromArgb(200, 200, 200)`). -- Only use `New` when you _**don't**_ intend to set it afterwards (i.e. `Dim b As New Button` `b.Text = "Click me" 'Here you are using the button directly after initialization, and you don't set the variable to a specific value`).

Comment: Consider the following two cases: https://pastebin.com/dUHeg3M7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close .. But this should do it

```
Dim nCol As  Color = Color.FromArgb(200, 200, 200)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have `Option Infer On`,

```
Dim nCol = Color.FromArgb(200, 200, 200)
```